# Sketchfab AJAX json call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to collect the url for a sketchfab model thumbnail.

view-source:https://api.sketchfab.com/v2/models/b894deeab7904df3a1f6016053604960

When ik go to the above url, I can see the information I need.

Now i'm trying to make an AJAX call so I can dynamicaly use the thumbnail url.

```js
$.ajax({
       url: 'https://api.sketchfab.com/v2/models/b894deeab7904df3a1f6016053604960',
       type: 'GET',
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function(data){
        alert(data);
       }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Somehow, i'm just getting [object Object] back, I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Probably something stupid...

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting back the JSON data in object form - to make it readable you need to stringify it:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data))
```

But you shouldn't really need to do this, other than to make it readable, so just work with what you get back.